# How to redirect stdout with '\r' printed on the same line?

Tags: c, stdout, carriage-return

Check below the code snippet of using the character `\r`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        printf("%d%%\r", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(1e4);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program on the console has only 1 line:

```
$ ./main
100%
```

However if the output is redirected to a file `./main > main.log`, the file has 100 lines:

```
1%
2%
3%
...
100%
```

**Question**:

How do I keep only the last line of output to the log file?

Comment: Don't write to `stdout`. Open `"/dev/tty"` as a file, and write to that, It won't be redirected.

Comment: If you print the file with `cat` it should display in the same way, but of course the extra data is still there, it just gets overwritten on the terminal. You can't unwrite data that you have written to stdout. Note that `\r` doesn't actually erase the previous line, so parts of it will show if the new line is shorter.

Comment: If you `cat main.log`, sure, it'll contain 100 lines, but it'll display just the `100%`, same as your terminal does.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: I think the OP *wants* the file to be updated, they just want the intermediate and end results to look the same as it does at the console.

Comment: In that case the OP needs to learn to use `seek()`.

Comment: Then he can write the "100%" to stdout as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yar. They'd need to test using `fstat` to distinguish `S_ISREG` from other possible `stdout`s, and either print carriage returns (for non-files, where you hope it works as expected) or `fseek` (for files) depending on the result of the test.

Comment: Could also just look at `isatty()` and only print anything other than 100% when it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is part of a larger program where the "percentage" may or may not be 100% (otherwise, you could just print 100% right away).
So you could check if the output goes to a terminal using [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html). If not, print the "last percentage" value:

```
int main(void)
{
    int b = isatty(STDOUT_FILENO);
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        if (b) printf("%d%%\r", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(1e4);
    }
    if (!b) printf("%d%%\r", i-1);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```